# Search & replace serialized data after moving the files directory

Tags: 6, migrations

A drupal 6 content_field_video table holds serialized data with URLs pointing to the old site location - `sites/default/files/thumb.png`. Moving to the otherwise amazing Aegir-based omega8 hosting platform, we moved to a new files directory,  `sites/MYSITE.COM/files/thumb.png`,  so we need to convert to URLs to a new scheme. Most of the URLs are corrected by the omega8 import process, but video thumbnails are hardcoded.

What's the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The [scanner](https://drupal.org/project/scanner) module scans all CCK fields - Since this is a CCK field, it should correct this kind of problem, if this is a small database. But for large database it may suffer from performance issues.

You can also do it [with PHP](http://caritatis.wordpress.com/2010/06/18/fixing-paths-in-drupal-database/) or [SQL](http://data.stackexchange.com/drupal%20answersmeta/query/80128/sql-search-and-replace).